# Galvanic Cells, theoritical voltage

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry

This reaction proceeds in the galvanic cell:

$$\ce{Zn + Pb^{2+} -> Zn^{2+} + Pb}$$

I need the equation for the half-reactions of this cell and the theoretical voltage produced by this cell if concentration of $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ is $\mathrm{0.1\ mol/L}$ and concentration of $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ is $\mathrm{10^{-4}\ mol/L}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$Pb^{2+} + 2e^{-}->Pb  E_{0}(Pb^{2+}) = -0.1263$$
$$Zn->Zn^{2+} +2e^{-}   E_{0}(Zn^{2+}) = -0.76 $$

$$[Zn^{2+}] = 0.1 mol/L [Pb^{2+}] = 10^{-4} mol/L$$

$$Qc= \frac{[Zn^{2+}]}{[Pb^{2+}]}$$
$$E_{0}(cell) = E_{0}(Pb^{2+})- E_{0}(Zn^{2+})= -0.1263 - (-0.76) $$
$$ E(cell)= E_{0}(cell) - \frac {RT ln Q_{c}}{nF}$$

Small piece of advice : Tag homework and exercises on these type of questions , read through "*[Help Center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help)*" specifically "Asking" . Try to attempt the question by yourself and show your own attempt of an answer. This site isnt "Solve my homework site " good luck cheers

Comment: Thank you, I tried and submit, teacher said it is wrong ,thats why i wrote it here.

Comment: Well if you did something post that here , only then people will try to answer i think . anyway this is still in beta so i guess moderators arent here yet .or your post would have been downvoted/removed